# How to add value on select tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add value to the text box of the drop down `<select>` tag in HTML with JavaScript. This is my code:

```js
function disableTip() {
  document.getElementById('cars').value = 'Hello';
}
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button onclick="disableTip()">Click me</button>
```

When i click the button the textbox becomes empty doesn't write "Hello". Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to add another option to the select or force the select value ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis no just on the textbox of that  drop down to write hello

Comment: There is no text box. Select elements create drop down menus, not comboboxes.

Comment: Your code is trying to set the value of the `select` element, not add anything. If you want to add an option you could do `document.getElementById('cars').appendChild( new Option( 'Hello' ) )`. The `select` empties because the value 'Hello' doesn't exist in your `select` element, so no selection is made.

Comment: @somethinghere But even if i replace the Hello with saab which exists inside the select still wont show.

Comment: All I can say is that when you have `<option value="saab">Saab</option>` using `select.value = 'saab'` should show saab as the selected value.